# How to run shell command in background with multiple commands in one line

Tags: shell

I want to run multiple commands **in one line**, and one of them have to run in background.

Script like that:

```
cd /tmp; python -m SimpleHTTPServer &; echo "Hello"
```

I want to `cd` to */tmp* directory, and then brings up the python simplehttpserver in the background, on the same time run `echo "Hello"`, but it turns out

```
 syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `&` is already separator in sh/bash. Does this do what you want?

  `cd /tmp; python -m SimpleHTTPServer & echo "Hello"`
- You can also try `eval`

  `cd /tmp; eval "python -m SimpleHTTPServer &" ; echo "Hello"`